# Employer responses to signing off

Tags: united-kingdom, stress

I work in UK academia in a moderately senior position and am already planning to change jobs as I am overwhelmingly stressed at work. I have recently seen a doctor and they have recommended signing me off for two weeks.

What must, and can, an employer do if I accept this? I am worried it will damage my chance of getting future jobs or get me fired from this one when I go back.

Are they required to offer me the option of reducing my workload or changing position if other positions are available? If they do this, how would it appear on a standard HR reference?

Comment: If you are in academia chances are you would have a union that could help answer this best.  This is bordering on legal advice.

Comment: Any chance the 2 downvoters can offer some explanations or suggestions?

Comment: I am not familiar with UK workplace practices, but prima facie this question seems fine to me. A competent HR familiar with the work practices should be able to answer these questions, so as of now, this seems on-topic here.

Comment: In what way did your doctor "recommend" it? If you are seriously ill, he could just write you a doctors note and you take two weeks of medical leave. I'm not that familiar with UK law, but to my understanding you can not be fired for being ill.

Comment: Why *already planning* as in *sooner than expected?* Broadly speaking, [the UK law](https://www.unison.org.uk/get-help/knowledge/health-and-safety/stress/) puts some obligations on the employer to conduct risk assessment and manage stress levels, etc. There is also an expectation that certain stress levels are normal and expected; also it may depend on a person. I think expanding your answer would halp as it's not clear whether the significant levels of stress you are experiencing are employer's fault.

Comment: @Polygnome this seems to be straying off-topic a bit, but they told me they would write a note if I wanted but for various reasons (including noone to cover my area right now) I'm considering that a last resort since it could create more problems.

Answer (score 10):

Mate, if you're signed off, you're signed off.

Unless you're in your probation period, sacking you for being signed off is more of a headache for your employer than it's worth, and that's doubly true if you're off for workplace stress.

Just take that time off, apply for a new job, **do not start until your sick note ends** and get on with life. The new employer has no rights to ask the old one about your sick levels.

Comment: and do NOT use the sick leave period for job interviews.

Comment: @jwenting This should be emphasised, not just because of the issues from doing work while claiming to be sick - but because **you shouldn't do anything other than rest if that's what your doctor ordered. Including writing job applications.**

Comment: The problem with academia is that it can be a tight knit community - HR people may talk between each other, off the record, and attendance may certainly be mentioned during such conversations.  And unless you get told why your job application is rejected, there is utterly nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @Moo I'm intending to leave academia, so that's less of a concern.

Comment: @jwenting & bilkokuya could you elaborate - is this for medical or legal reasons? The doctor said I should avoid anything to do with my *current* job, because it was the source of the stress; they actively told me *not* to treat it as a physical rest period but to get out and do things I wanted to do for myself - under which I would include taking steps to get a less stressful job.

Comment: @anonymised for medical reasons you should stay away from your current work environment. For legal and contractual reasons you should not engage in any other professional endeavours. For medical reasons too, doing anything that increases your stress levels (and job hunting is very stressful) is not a good idea if you're on medical leave for stress induced conditions.